# Cleaner Code for custom query

Tags: ruby

Is there a cleaner way to do the following?

```
friend_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
friendIDsQuery = ""
friend_ids.each_with_index do |friend_id, index|
  friendIDsQuery += "SELECT id FROM test WHERE user_id = #{friend_id}"

  if index != friend_ids.size - 1
    friendIDsQuery += " INTERSECT "
  end
end
```

Basically I'm passing in an array of IDs, and building a custom INTERSECT query.

Comment: you wrote Array#join by hand...

Answer (score 4):

```
query = friend_ids.map {|id| "SELECT id FROM test WHERE user_id=#{id}"}.join " INTERSECT "
```

*Bam.*

Edit: Ok, well, not just *bam*. First of all, if you're using Rails, go with something like NewAlexandria's answer, because it doesn't involve raw string interpolation (which quickly leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities). To make the above a little more safe (and assuming the IDs are integers), you should probably do

```
query = friend_ids.map { |id|
  "SELECT id FROM test WHERE user_id = #{id.to_i}"
}.join " INTERSECT "
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be the more *idiomatic* Rails form, without so much SQL.

```
friend_ids.
  map {|fid| Test.select(:id).where(:user_id => fid) }.
  reduce {|a,e| a = a & e }
```

If you *really* need the sql, then append:

`.to_sql`

Comment: You're missing the intersection-part. As far as I can tell, OP isn't trying to find ids where `user_id IN (...)`, but the intersection of multiple selections.

Comment: @Flambino you're right.  Here is the correct for with intersections.  I do concede that leaving the intersects within the database may be more performant than to do *N* queries and then operate upon them.

Comment: +1. I'd say your solution has the distinct advantage of not generating a query string "by hand". In my answer I'm assuming that the IDs are safe - otherwise, well, hello injection attacks (should probably note that in my answer). Meanwhile, you're assuming that it's Rails. Very probable, but OP doesn't say. As for performance, your guess is as good as mine - OP doesn't say mention anything about the number of queries.

Comment: the OP didn't specify whether ActiveRecord or Rails was being used. Anyway, refactor of the reduce: `reduce([], :&)`.

Comment: @tokland though *arcane*, that's hot